# datastax opscenter posturl.conf doesn't posting alerts

Tags: datastax

I have testing the `datastax ops center alerts` for my infrastructure i am trying to post alerts with `http post` , i have tried basic tutorial in `datastax` docs but getting errors
I have getting errors in `opscentered.log` is

```
 [Test_Cluster] ERROR: 401 Unauthorized Error pushing event to posturl plugin
INFO: Stopping factory <HTTPClientFactory: http://myserverurl/postOPSCevents.php>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your web server and posting script to receive alerts? It's step 2 in the DataStax documentation for enabling alerts.  I specifically ask about that step since the 401 Error is a http authentication error.